# insert unknown number of inputs to database

Tags: php

I have 2 tables inside the database, the questions table, and the chances table.
the problem is that I want the user to be able to add more chances by clicking the button which says: "INSERT MORE INPUTS OF CHANCES[]", I don't know how to tell PHP to insert this unknown number of inputs to the database.

```
// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $title= $_POST['question'];
    $timer= $_POST['timer'];
    $points= $_POST['points'];
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO questions (title, timer, points)
        VALUES ('$title','$timer','$points')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) {
    echo "QUESTION ADDED TO DB SUCCESSFULLY!";
    echo "ADDING CHANCES TO THEIR TABLE...";


    $questionid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $titles= $_POST['chance']; //the problem starts from here
    $status= 0; //initially

    $sql = "INSERT INTO chances (questionid, titles, status)
    VALUES ('$questionid','$titles','$status')";

} else {
    echo "Error QUESTION DIDN'T ADDED: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
    <h1>new question</h1>
    <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="question">
    <input type="num" name="timer" placeholder="timer">
    <input type="num" name="points" placeholder="points">
    <br><br>
    <h1>question chances</h1>
      <input type="text" name="chance[]" placeholder="chance-1">
      <input type="text" name="chance[]" placeholder="chance-2">
      <input type="text" name="chance[]" placeholder="chance-3">
      <input type="text" name="chance[]" placeholder="chance-4">
        <br>
      <button>INSERT MORE INPUTS OF CHANCES[]</button>
     <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case $_POST['chance'] is a array which includes all the chance inputs. Loop through it and insert them to the database one by one inside the loop.

```
 foreach ($_POST['chance'] as $chance){              
   $sql = "INSERT INTO chances (questionid, titles, status) VALUES ($questionid,$chance,$status)";
   mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was vulnerable to SQL injection so the following illustrates how you could use `prepared statements` to mitigate the threat. As you are using `chance[]` as the name you effectively POST an array so you can iterate through the POSTed values and execute an insert statement for each chance in this array.
The button doesn't appear to do anything in the original question so I improvised the means by which a new `chance` input element might be added prior to form submission. Hope it helps

```
<?php

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'I-am-Gr00t'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $results=array();

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){

        $chances=isset( $_POST['chance'] ) ? $_POST['chance'] : false;

        if( !empty( $chances ) ){

            $args=array(
                'question'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'timer'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
                'points'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
            );
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );

            # add the question using a prepared statement
            $sql='insert into `questions` (`title`, `timer`, `points`) values (?,?,?)';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('sii',$question,$timer,$points);
            $stmt->execute();


            # id for last record added
            $id=$db->insert_id;
            $results[]=$id ?  sprintf( 'Question "%s" added', $question ) : sprintf( 'Error: failed to add question "%s"',$question );

            if( $id ){
                #prepare & bind new insert statement
                $sql='insert into `chances` (`questionid`,`titles`,`status`) values (?,?,?)';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt->bind_param( 'isi', $id, $title, $status );

                $status=0;# this could simply be the default value in the chances table and thus be omitted here

                #add each chance
                foreach( $chances as $index => $title ){
                    $res=$stmt->execute();
                    $results[]=$res ? sprintf( 'Chance "%s" added', $title ) : sprintf( 'Error: failed to add "%s"', $title );
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
        body, body *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:monospace}
        fieldset{border:none;margin:2rem 0;padding:0.5rem;box-shadow:2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,150,0.1);border-radius:0.5rem;}
        .chances{margin:0.5rem;}
        .chances > input,
        button,
        [type='submit']{margin:0.25rem!important;padding:0.25rem}
        [name='chance[]']{width:120px}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <h1>new question</h1>
            <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="question" />
            <input type="num" name="timer" placeholder="timer" />
            <input type="num" name="points" placeholder="points" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h1>question chances</h1>
            <div class='chances'>
                <input type="text" name="chance[]" value='chance-1' placeholder="chance-1" />
                <input type="text" name="chance[]" value='chance-2' placeholder="chance-2" />
                <input type="text" name="chance[]" value='chance-3' placeholder="chance-3" />
                <input type="text" name="chance[]" value='chance-4' placeholder="chance-4" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <button type='button' name='add'>INSERT MORE INPUTS OF CHANCES[]</button>
            <input type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
        <?php
            if( !empty( $results ) )printf('<pre>%s</pre>',implode(PHP_EOL,$results));
        ?>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.querySelector( 'button[name="add"]' ).addEventListener('click', e=> {
            let col=document.querySelectorAll('input[name="chance[]"]');
            let l=col.length;
            let i=l+1;

            let input=col[ l - 1 ];
            let clone=input.cloneNode( true );
                clone.removeAttribute('placeholder');
                clone.setAttribute( 'placeholder', 'chance-' + i );
                clone.value=clone.getAttribute('placeholder');

            input.parentNode.insertBefore( clone, input.nextSibling );
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```